# Getting 401 Unauthorized Issue when submitting spark jobs on AWS EKS

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

We have an AWS EKS Cluster to which we are submitting spark jobs using an EC2 Instance.

The command used to submit spark jobs was -

```
bin/spark-submit \
    --master {cluster_ip} \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name sample_job \
    --conf spark.executor.cores=3 \
    --conf spark.driver.cores=3 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.request.cores=2.5 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.request.cores=2.5 \
    --conf spark.executor.memory=18G \
    --conf spark.driver.memory=18G \
    --conf {image_url} \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-sa \
    local:///opt/spark/work-dir/code/main.py
```

The job gets submitted successfully. After some time the Poller which starts polling the spark driver for completion starts giving out 401 Unauthorized errors.

Initially -

```
INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
```

After some time -

```
1/02/24 11:21:12 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:13 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:14 WARN WatchConnectionManager: Exec Failure: HTTP 401, Status: 401 - Unauthorized
java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '401 Unauthorized'
        at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.checkResponse(RealWebSocket.java:229)
        at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onResponse(RealWebSocket.java:196)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:203)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/02/24 11:21:14 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:15 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:16 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:17 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:18 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:19 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:20 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:21 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:22 WARN WatchConnectionManager: Exec Failure: HTTP 401, Status: 401 - Unauthorized
java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '401 Unauthorized'
        at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.checkResponse(RealWebSocket.java:229)
        at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onResponse(RealWebSocket.java:196)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:203)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/02/24 11:21:22 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:23 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:24 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
21/02/24 11:21:25 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application status for spark-e9376d3618ac4cdc9e4fa0ce46c80c67 (phase: Running)
```

Even If the driver pod gets completed it gets stuck infinitely in the running status due to the 401 error, While if the driver pod completes before this error then the poller gives out proper success or failure status.

Any particular reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: I hit the exactly same situation.

Comment: I am currently facing this issue. Please let me know how you have overcome this problem.